# How do you do modulo or remainder in Erlang?

Tags: erlang, modulo

I'm brand new to Erlang. How do you do modulo (get the remainder of a division)? It's % in most C-like languages, but that designates a comment in Erlang.

Several people answered with rem, which in most cases is fine. But I'm revisiting this because now I need to use negative numbers and rem gives you the remainder of a division, which is not the same as modulo for negative numbers.

Comment: The modulo operation has not one clear definition, btw for C and C++ %   for negative is implementation dependent (ISO C90) later standards define it exactly as Erlang for details see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In Erlang, `5 rem 3.` gives `2`, and `-5 rem 3.` gives `-2`.  If I understand your question, you would want `-5 rem 3.` to give 1 instead, since `-5 = -2 * 3 + 1.`

Does this do what you want?

```
mod(X,Y) when X > 0 -> X rem Y;
mod(X,Y) when X < 0 -> Y + X rem Y;
mod(0,Y) -> 0.
```

Comment: This will work. But is there really nothing distributed with erlang that does this?

Comment: Not according to the erlang reference manual: http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html (section 6.12)

Comment: Alternatively: mod(X,Y)->(X rem Y + Y) rem Y.

Answer (score 32):

The erlang modulo operator is `rem`

```
Eshell V5.6.4  (abort with ^G)
1> 97 rem 10.
7
```

Answer (score 10):

I used the following in elixir:

```
defp mod(x,y) when x > 0, do: rem(x, y);
defp mod(x,y) when x < 0, do: rem(x, y) + y;
defp mod(0,_y), do: 0
```

Comment: This is what [`Integer.mod/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Integer.html#mod/2) does.

Comment: This answer second clause contains error. It would function incorrectly for case, when x <0, but rem(x, y) ==0, for example -5, 5. In this case, the second clause would deliver 5 as result instead of 0

Answer (score 4):

According to [this blog post](http://jjinux.blogspot.com/2007/05/erlang-amazingly-funky-and-amazingly.html), it's `rem`.

Answer (score 4):

The above Y + X rem Y seems to be wrong: either (Y + X) rem Y or Y + (X rem Y) yield incorrect results. Ex: let Y=3. If X=-4, the first form returns -1, if X=-3 the second form returns 3, none of which is in [0;3[.

I use this instead:

```
% Returns the positive remainder of the division of X by Y, in [0;Y[. 
% In Erlang, -5 rem 3 is -2, whereas this function will return 1,  
% since -5 =-2 * 3 + 1.

modulo(X,Y) when X > 0 ->   
   X rem Y;

modulo(X,Y) when X < 0 ->   
    K = (-X div Y)+1,
    PositiveX = X + K*Y,
    PositiveX rem Y;

modulo(0,_Y) -> 
    0.
```

Answer (score 2):

Erlang remainder not works with negative numbers, so you have to write your own function for negative parameters.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is wrong.

`rem` behaves exactly like the `%` operator in modern C. It uses truncated division.

The accepted answer fails for X<0 and Y<0.  Consider `mod(-5,-3)`:

```
C:                     -5 % -3 == -2
rem:                 -5 rem -3 == -2
Y + X rem Y:    -3 + -5 rem -3 == -5 !! wrong !!
```

The alternative implementations for the modulo operator use floored division and Euclidean division. The results for those are

```
flooring division:   -5 mod -3 == -2
euclidean division:  -5 mod -3 == 1
```

So

```
Y + X rem Y
```

doesn't reproduce any modulo operator for X < 0 and Y < 0.

And `rem` works as expected -- it's using truncated division.

Answer (score 1):

```
mod(A, B) when A > 0 -> A rem B;
mod(A, B) when A < 0 -> mod(A+B, B); 
mod(0, _) -> 0.

% console:
3> my:mod(-13, 5).
2
```