# Why Rem operator in Elixir returns negative numbers?

Tags: elixir

I am trying a simple operation

```
rem(-1, 25)
```

I expect that to be the reminder of integer division and return 24 (the same e.g. as in Ruby) but it returns -1.
Am I doing something wrong? Is the behavior broken on elixir?

Comment: This is really a math/definition question - "remainder" is not specified unambiguously for negative numbers.

Comment: There are differences of opinion on whether remainder functions should provide positive or negative values when the input is negative. Both schools of thought are valid and unfortunately there's no consensus across languages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sign of the remainder actually changes per programming language: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation. So both are correct and both are wrong. :)

Comment: Would it not be useful then to add a modulo operation on Elixir like the one @simon-jez mentions? Modulo operations are very common for math related work like crypto.

Answer (score 7):

Ruby:

```
irb > -1.remainder(25) 
 => -1
```

Elixir:

```
iex(6)> rem(-1,25)
-1
```

They work the same.

But I think you mean modulo from Ruby:

```
irb > -1.modulo(25)
 => 24
```

If you need a function that behaves like this then I think that you need to write your own as [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/353224/408011).

Answer (score 3):

According to Davis Thomas in Programming Elixir:

> rem is the remainder operator. It is called as a function (rem(11, 3) => 2). It
>   differs from normal modulo operations in that the result will have the
>   same sign as the function’s first argument.

That means, in your case, which is rem(-1, 25), the result will have - sign, like the 1st arg.