# Modulo operator in Elixir

Tags: elixir, modulo

How do I use the modulo operator in Elixir?

For example in Ruby you can do:

```
5 % 2 == 0
```

How does it differ from Ruby's modulo operator?

Comment: https://elixirschool.com/en/lessons/basics/basics/#arithmetic

Comment: Note that "modulo operator" is am ambiguous term and can have different alogorithms, especially for negative numbers. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation - personally I consider the elixir `rem` operator to be a remainder operator, not a modulo operator.

Comment: @PenguinBrian That's my understanding too. Hence why I added the question how it differs from Ruby's modulo operator. But nobody mentioned that in their answers. Feel free to add one.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For integers, use [`Kernel.rem/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#rem/2):

```elixir
iex(1)> rem(5, 2)
1
iex(2)> rem(5, 2) == 0
false
```

From the docs:

> Computes the remainder of an integer division.
>
> `rem/2` uses truncated division, which means that the result will always
>   have the sign of the `dividend`.
>
> Raises an `ArithmeticError` exception if one of the arguments is not an
>   integer, or when the `divisor` is 0.

The main differences compared to Ruby seem to be:

1. `rem` only works with integers, but `%` changes its behavior completely depending on the datatype.
2. The sign is negative for negative dividends in Elixir (the same as Ruby's [`remainder`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Integer.html#method-i-remainder)):

Ruby:

```elixir
irb(main):001:0> -5 / 2
=> -3
irb(main):002:0> -5 % 2
=> 1
irb(main):003:0> -5.remainder(2)
=> -1
```

Elixir:

```elixir
iex(1)> -5 / 2
-2.5
iex(2)> rem(-5, 2)
-1
```

Elixir's `rem` just uses Erlang's `rem`, so [this related Erlang question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353224/how-do-you-do-modulo-or-remainder-in-erlang) may also be useful.

Answer (score 7):

Use `rem/2` see: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#rem/2
So in Elixir your example becomes:

```
rem(5,2) == 0
```

which returns `false`

BTW what you wrote using `%`  in Elixir simply starts a comment to the end of the line.

Comment: `%` starts a comment in Erlang, not in Elixir. Elixir uses `#` for that.

Answer (score 5):

Use `Integer.mod/2`, see: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Integer.html#mod/2

```
iex>Integer.mod(-5, 2)
1
```

Comment: Only if you really want the modulo. Most of the time you want a remainder. 2 goes into -5 twice, leaving you with -1, not 1.